# How to update only one object property or multiple in an array using ngrx state in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngrx

I have an array of elements which I am storing in a state, the array would have look something like this:

```
filterList: Array<any> = [
    {name: "Branch", filters: [{value: "Location 1", status: "unselected"}, {value: "Location 2", status: "selected"}]},
    {name: "Segment", filters: [{value: "Segment 1", status: "selected"}, {value: "Segment 2", status: "selected"}]},
     ...... and so on
]
```

The array is a huge list, where I would like to add an object to the `filters` array or change the `status` property from `unselected` to `selected` or even add more objects to the `filterList`.

How do I set the state, to only change the things I needed and not the entire array? As of now, I have been trying few things, but couldn't work them out.
Here is the one I tried.

```
case FilterActions.FILTER_LIST:
   return {
      ...state,
      filterList: [...state, action.payload]
   };
```

And also how do I dispatch the actions to update only a few elements at a time?
I have been trying to do it like this.

```
this.store.dispatch(new MainActions.FilterListActions([{name: "Branch"}, filters: [{value: "Location 1", status: "selected"}]]));
```

Please help me out this.

**Update**

Here's the code for `store.actions.ts`

```
import {Action} from '@ngrx/store';

export const FILTER_LIST = 'FILTER_LIST';

export class FilterListAction implements Action {
  readonly type = FILTER_LIST;
  constructor (public payload: Array<any>) {}
}

export type FilterActions = FilterListAction;
```

Here's the code for the `store.reducer.ts` file:

```
import * as FilterActions from './store.actions';

const initialState = {
  filterList: []
};

export function filtersReducer(state = initialState, action: FilterActions.FilterActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
     case FilterActions.FILTER_LIST:
        return {
          ...state,
          filterList: [...state, action.payload]
        };
     default: return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the code for `FilterListActions`

Answer (score 1):

I belive you can use simple js/ts function 'find' to get this done.

```
let filterList: Array<any> = [
    {name: "Branch", filters: [{value: "Location 1", status: "unselected"}, {value: "Location 2", status: "selected"}]},
    {name: "Segment", filters: [{value: "Segment 1", status: "selected"}, {value: "Segment 2", status: "selected"}]},
     ...... and so on
]
```

consider the case where you need to added object

```
  let toBeAddedFilter = {value: "Location 1", status: "unselected"}
```

to `filters` where `name= "Branch"`.

Then you use `filter()` like

```
filterList.find(x=>x.name=="Branch").filters.push(toBeAddedFilter);
```

also to change status of one specific location of a specific branch

```
filterList.find(x=>x.name=="Branch")
    .filters.find(y=>y.value="Location 1").status ='selected';
```

I belive you can make a function for each need out of this example. This does not change the complete array.

To complete 
Pass the value of the filtercategory name using a function to your custom array update function if the filter category change. if it is something inside filters of one filter category pass that too.
 the functions can be like `okThisChanged(filtercategory,value,newStatus)` for edit and `okThisFilterAdded(filtercategory,newlyAddedFilter)` for add

Comment: The changes can be of any type, so is there any way I could know if it should be updated or added or removed.

Comment: how are you gonna know when changes occur if you dont know what changed??

Comment: Is there a form submit. what object does it give u.? is it the filter object? is it the branch object? or is it the complete filterlist

Comment: There are a bunch of filter categories, a filter category (something like Branch or Segment) can be added or removed, and each category has lots of checkboxes, which gives filter values

Comment: Pass the value of the filtercategory name using a function to ur custom array update function if the filter category change. if it is something inside filters of one filter category pass that too. the function can be like okThisChanged(filtercategory,value,newStatus) and okThisFilterAdded(filtercategory,newlyAddedFilter)

Comment: you can know what changes from ui as these things i expect are gonna be binded to different fields or forms in the ui. There u use differen functions to bind to different buttons like addFilter, editFilter, Etc, and finalise the change on save